# Android Socket InputStream problem

Tags: java, android

I have a server written in VB, it sends data to clients in periods of 3 seconds. I've written a client Java code like this:

```
class Commu extends Thread {
   Socket socket;
   InputStream inputStream;
   OutputStream outputStream;

   public Commu() {
      try {
         socket=new Socket();
         socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.0.1", 1234)));

         inputStream=socket.getInputStream();
         outputStream=socket.getOutputStream();
         this.start();
      } catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
      }
   }

   public void run() {
      while(true) {
         byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
         inputStream.read(buffer);
         System.out.println(buffer[0]);
      }
   }
}
```

It works fine on my desktop, it prints message whenever the VB server sends message.

It works on Android, but the inputStream read only once, and then get stuck; If I want to read more data, I have to use `outputStream` to send some data, then `inputStream` will read once, and get stuck again. That is really strange, could anyone tell me why?

There is no problem in `System.out.print()`, because DDMS can show it, I promise! The problem is `inputStream` should not read only once, it should read when data comes. But it didn't , it read only once.

Even if, I only print one byte from the buffer, it get stuck on Android. It works very well on desktop, but get stuck on Android.

Comment: I think you removed the interesting thing (in the while loop). Also, use Log.d() instead of system.out.println...

Answer (score 0):

That's a wierd piece of code. You don't check the return value of read() for -1, i.e. EOS, and you only display the first byte of the data received and throw the rest away.